# display activity indicator in iphone titanium

Tags: iphone, titanium, uiactivityindicatorview

I tried everything in order to display an `activity indicator` inside my iphone app build in titanium.

I did this:

```
var activityIndicator = Titanium.UI.createActivityIndicator();
Ti.UI.currentWindow.add(activityIndicator);
activityIndicator.show();
```

and I got this

```
"invalid method (createActivityIndicator) passed to UIModule";
```

I also tried this:

```
  var activityIndicator = Ti.UI.createActivityIndicator({
  color: 'green',
  font: {fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue', fontSize:26, fontWeight:'bold'},
  message: 'Loading...',
  style:Ti.UI.iPhone.ActivityIndicatorStyle.DARK,
  top:10,
  left:10,
  height:'auto',
  width:'auto'
});

  win2.add(activityIndicator);
```

and this:

```
     var dialog = Titanium.UI.createActivityIndicator();
   dialog.message = "Loading...";
   window.add(dialog);
   dialog.show();
```

but obviously `NOTHING` works. Anyone, any idea about how to make this work?

Comment: I get no error now, but it doesn't show up any activityIndicator!!!!!

Comment: @adrian: your code seems fine... Are you using Android or iPhone simulator ?

Answer (score 1):

One thing to remember is that when you do a full build Titanium removes unused components from their API. So if you are adding a new type of component, for example, there are no textAreas in your app, and then you add a textArea, you may get this error.

The solution is to force a total rebuild by clearing out the contents of your build/iphone directory.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `width, height` of the activityIndicator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this its working for me :

```
var activityIndicator = Titanium.UI.createActivityIndicator
    ({
        style: Ti.UI.iPhone.ActivityIndicatorStyle.PLAIN,
        font: {fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue', fontSize:18,fontWeight:'bold'},
        color: 'Black',
        message:'Loading...',
        width:'auto',
        top:'50dp',
        left:'100dp' ,
        height:'80dp',
    });
    win.add(activityIndicator);
```

It works for both Android and iPhone.

Comment: it didn't worked for me but i solved my issue after all! i was testing it both on iphone simulator and device!

Comment: I don't really know. I used some code from KitchenSink app. when they were playing a movie they were having an activity indicator before video was charging...so i used that. don't know why mine didn't work! BTW: you are here all the time?